# Coincidencias de cadenas de texto en Python 3

Tags: python

Estimados, alguien conoce un método para encontrar coincidencias no exactas entre cadenas de texto?

Por ejemplo:

Tengo el siguiente texto "STATUS MSG PACK ACM L" (columna 1) y debería devolverme "PACK L" (columna 2).

Tengo 2 listas, una escrita por una persona que son textos más largos y otra que corresponde al mensaje a buscar que es el correcto.

Adjunto un ejemplo de las dos listas: la columna 1 se debe buscar en la columna 2, y arrojar el elemento de la columna 2 más asociado:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B11sJdX_AaJBd2lvWGszaFpXM2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Viendo la planilla, entiendo que "STATUS MSG PACK ACM L" se correspondería con "RECIRC FAN LWR R" confirma esto por que si es así no necesitas una búsqueda difusa, sino una lista de tuplas, dónde buscas por una columna y retornas el valor de la otra.

Comment: Hola,  "STATUS MSG PACK ACM L" se debe asociar al elemento más parecido en ese caso corresponde a "PACK L" que está en algún lugar de la columna 2

Comment: Ok, entiendo, ahora por que dices que `STATUS MSG PACK ACM L`debe "matchearse" con `PACK L` si en la misma segunda columnas tienes `PACK ACM L` ? Cualquier forma de búsqueda difusa me parece que encontraría más parecido `PACK ACM L`  que `PACK L`.

Comment: Para cada elemento de la columna 1 debo arrojar uno de la columna 2. En ese caso para para todos de la columna 1 que contengan "PACK L" dentro de la cadena, debería arrojar "PACK L" como resultado

Comment: Jorge, cualquier solución de búsqueda no exacta va a encontrar que `PACK ACM L` es más parecido a `STATUS MSG PACK ACM L` que `PACK L`, simplemente por que coinciden mas palabras 3, versus 2. O no te estoy entendiendo, o el ejemplo no es el adecuado.

Comment: Disculpa me equivoqué de archivo, ya que la columna 2 solo es de 45 elementos y solo está PACK L, ahora la subo @PatricioMoracho listo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para búsquedas difusas hay mútiples herramientas y métodos, pero usando Python de fabrica contamos ya, con la librería base [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) que nos permite obtener un `ratio` de semejanza entre cadenas. Por ejemplo:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher as SM

s1 = 'Hola Mundo'
s2 = 'Hola Mundo cruel'
print(SM(None, s1, s2).ratio())

s1 = 'Hola Mundo'
s2 = 'Hola Mundo!'
print(SM(None, s1, s2).ratio())
> 0.7692307692307693
> 0.9523809523809523
```

En este ejemplo medimos la semejanza de `Hola Mundo`con otras cadenas y vemos que lógicamente `Hola Mundo!` obtiene un ratio de semejanza mayor que `Hola Mundo cruel`. La idea entonces, sería recorrer una lista, y por cada elemento, verificar los ratios con respecto a los elemento de la segunda lista, el mayor será el más semejante. Algo así:

```
import difflib

lista1 = ["STATUS MSG PACK ACM L"]
lista2 = ["LOW LIMIT VALVE L",
          "LOW LIMIT VALVE R",
          "PACK ACM L",
          "PACK ACM R",
          "PACK L",
          "PACK MODE L",]

d = difflib.Differ()

for search in lista1:
  matches = sorted(lista2, key=lambda x: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x, search).ratio(), reverse=True)    
  print("{0} se compara con {1} el más parecido es {2}".format(search, matches, matches[0]))
```

En `matches` terminamos teniendo los elemente de la segunda lista, ordenados de mayor semejanza a menor, el primer elemento debiera ser el óptimo.

**Importante**: De esta forma siempre vamos a encontrar un "parecido", como mejora adicional tal vez debas contemplar un `ratio` mínimo de semejanza para considerar que se ha logrado el "matching", éste valor lo puedes definir únicamente experimentando.

Mejor aún la forma sugerida por FjSevilla por ser más compacta y por que ya incorpora la lógica para evaluar el ratio mínimo :

```
matches = difflib.get_close_matches(search, possibilities = lista2, n = 1, cutoff = 0.6)
```

Como curiosidad, faltaría indicar que [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) esta basada fuertemente en el algoritmo [THE GESTALT APPROACH](http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/DDJ/1988/8807/8807c/8807c.htm) de 1987.

Comment: Buena respuesta Patricio. La verdad es que he usado esta biblioteca un par de veces para comparar archivos y me encanta. En este caso podria usar simplemente algo como `difflib.get_close_matches("STATUS MSG PACK ACM L", possibilities = lista2, n = 1,  cutoff = 0.6))` Lo cual le retornaria una lista que solo contiene el más semejante (o vacia si no lo hay). `cutoff` es el ratio minimo y debe ser definido empiricamente como comentas. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla, es sin duda una forma más óptima y simple, la incorporo a la respuesta. Saludos